# Makefile compiling even though header files doesn't change

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile which compiles a program with many dependencies like this:

```
CXX=g++
IDIR=lib
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2 -std=c++11 -I$(IDIR)

UDIR=utils
CFILES=Utils.cpp Structs.cpp Registry.cpp Dealer.cpp
CFILES:=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(UDIR)/%.cpp,$(CFILES))

DEPS=$(wildcard $(IDIR)/*.hh)

ODIR=obj
OBJ:=$(patsubst $(UDIR)/%.cpp,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(CFILES))


CDIR=strategies
EXTRA_CFILES=$(wildcard $(CDIR)/Strategy*.cpp)
CFILES += $(EXTRA_CFILES)

EXTRA_OBJ:=$(patsubst $(CDIR)/%.cpp,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(EXTRA_CFILES))
OBJ += $(EXTRA_OBJ)


all: create_header environment.exe

create_header:
    chmod +x create_headers.sh
    bash create_headers.sh

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(UDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(CDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

environment.o: environment.cpp $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

environment.exe: environment.o $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

m='Auto'
git_upload:
    git add -A
    git commit -m "$(m)"
    git push

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(ODIR)/*.o *.exe
```

However, when I type make, it is always compiling everything. I only want it to compile the dependencies when a change has been made, either to header or implementation files. The problem is, it is always compiling everything even though I haven't changed anything.

Comment: What does `create_headers.sh` do? Is it possible that's touching a bunch of header files?

Comment: Also possibly: `DEPS=$(wildcard $(IDIR)/*.hh)` followed by `$(ODIR)/%.o: $(UDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)` means that you're saying that every `.o` file depends on every `.hh` file.

Comment: Because it is true that they depend on almost all of the .hh files. But I want the makefile to not compile if I don’t change any .hh. With respect to create_headers.sh, it creates a file including the .hh but it doesn’t modify them.

Comment: It creates a file... where? Named what? Because if it creates a file named `./lib/all_headers.hh` or something, that would explain your problem.

Comment: I have deleted that command and I still have the same problem. It isn't that.

Comment: I tried what Nathan Pierson said and it worked, changing $(DEPS) TO $(IDIR)/%.hh solved the problem. However, I don't understand why.

Comment: `wildcard` is a different function than the stem-matching with `%`. The former takes *all* files found at the incited location while the latter only names one file which matches the stem. It could be that you have another problem now, in that not everything compiles now, because the dependency is just on the `.hh` file which matches exactly to the `.cpp` file.